# Why is hyperref resulting in an error on \begin{document}

Tags: hyperref

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{textcomp,xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{\itshape#3}{#3}{}{}

\name{Oliver}{Price}

\address{...}{}{} 

\phone[mobile]{...}      

\email{...}                                


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
```

This is returning an error on

```
\begin{document}
```

Why is this and how can I resolve it?

Comment: `moderncv` already loads `hyperref`.

Comment: So does that mean that in my text I can just write \href{...}{link} and it will work?

Comment: Did you try? `;-)`

Comment: Haha, just tried. Do you know how to get it to underscore when the mouse is hovered above it? Or alternatively to appear blue, like most links?

Comment: Just like you would do it it you would have loaded `hyperref`.